# Write all variables set in a shell script to file?

Tags: bash, file, shell, variables, zsh

Is there a way to output all the variables set in a (zsh/bash-)script? To clarify, I don't want the environment variables, just the ones the script has created.

Of course I could output each and every variable separately, but there's plenty of them... And running "*set*" gives me *all* variables.

Best,

Gerhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any direct way to do it, but you you could run `set` or `env` at the start and at the end of the script and compare them?

Comment: Good idea - that was too easy ;)  although it is strange that there is not a direct way...